# Finding root of a current index

Tags: solr, indexing, index

Is there a way to get the index root.

I am able to find the current index using the following code

```
indexService.GetContentIndexName()
```

How can I get the current Root defined inside the index ?

[image: index-root]

Comment: You can have multiple roots for the same location tag, what do you want to achieve here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest code would be like that:

```
var crawler = Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName).Crawlers.First() as SitecoreItemCrawler;
string rootString = crawler.Root;
Item rootItem = crawler.RootItem;
```

It assumes that there is one crawler defined only.

You should add some null checks, but I skipped them for clarity.